# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model_mixins'

Tags: django

**Python 3.8**

**models.py**

```
from gettext import gettext

import omnibus.model_mixins.general as general
from django.db import models

import model_mixins


class Client(general.NameMixin,
             general.FlagMixin,
             model_mixins.DirMixin,
             general.ArchivedMixin,
             general.CommentMixin,
             models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = gettext("Client")
        verbose_name_plural = gettext("Clients")
```

**model_mixins.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.db.models import Index
    from django.utils.translation import gettext
    
    
    class DirMixin:
        dir = models.CharField(max_length=30,
                               unique=True,
                               verbose_name=gettext("Target directory"))
    
        class Meta:
            abstract = True
            Index(fields=['dir', ])
```

**tree**

```
    ├── ads6
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   └── urls.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── clients
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── model_mixins.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   └── models.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── db.sqlite3
**migrations**
(venv) michael@michael:~/PycharmProjects/ads6/ads6$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads6/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads6/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads6/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads6/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads6/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/ads6/ads6/clients/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    import model_mixins
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model_mixins'
(venv) michael@michael:~/PycharmProjects/ads6/ads6$
```

Could you help me cope with this problem? I don't want to use "from import". I'd like to stick to "import model_mixins".

Comment: `from . import model_mixins`? The restriction on `from import` is not very useful. What would prevent you from doing that?

Comment: I've read that in some cases just import can prevent circular import hell. But anyway, is just import possible here?

Comment: Requires needless workarounds (in fact I would discourage you from them). Who told you avoiding `from ___ import ___` would prevent circular imports? One can still make a circular import without using those. If such syntax was not meant to be used why would it even be present in python?

Answer (score 1):

Tru to use this :-

```
from .model_mixins import DirMixin
```

instead of :-

```
from . import model_mixins
```